# Send push message to Messenger bot users

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to be able to send push messages to my Messenger bot's users at any time. I get the user ID thanks to:

```
event.sender.id
```

Then I try to send this POST request according to [the Messenger doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference). It returns "success" but I don't receive any message. The bot is in development.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "1451521288246029" // this is my sender id
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<TOKEN>"
```

Any idea how to be able to send a push message?

Comment: Where are event.sender.id coming from?

Comment: Is it possible that user is not the admin of the page that bot is assigned to? While bot is in development it can only communicate with admins of that page.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm admin of the page. I will try to publish the app to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I was using the "messenger_profile" endpoint instead of the "messages" one.